# Generating Components without *.spec.ts in Angular 6

Tags: angular6

In previous version, spec.ts can be disabled with .angular-cli.json as below.
Is there any way to do it with angular.json in version 6.0.0?

```
"defaults": {
    "component": { 
        "spec": false 
    },
    "service": { 
        "spec": false 
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: Per https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-workspace I'd guess you do it through the workspace schematics configuration. See e.g. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/v6.0.0-rc.8/packages/%40angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json#L74-L144 for components.

Comment: Thanks for the guide "@schematics/angular:component": 
{
      "prefix": "fmyp",
      "styleext": "css",
      "spec": false
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "fmp",
      "spec": false
    },
    "@schematics/angular:module": {
      "spec": false
    }

Answer (score 14):

in version "6.0.0" *.spec.ts can be disabled with angular.json

**NOTE:** don't forget to change the "prefix" property values "fmyp" and "fmp" to yours.

```
"schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "fmyp",
      "styleext": "css",
      "spec": false
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "fmp",
      "spec": false
    },
    "@schematics/angular:module": {
      "spec": false
    },
    "@schematics/angular:service": {
      "spec": false
    },
    "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
      "spec": false
    },
    "@schematics/angular:class": {
      "spec": false
    }
  }
```

Comment: Note that since Angular 9 this option was renamed to `"skipTests": true`. When doing an ng update it should automatically correct this

Answer (score 11):

Easy way is you can use CLI as you used with previous versions.

New syntax is `ng generate component component-name --skipTests=true`

This will create the component without .spec file.
Happy coding :)

Answer (score 10):

**Method 1:**

You can also disable spec generation at the time of creating things using Angular-cli by adding "--no-spec"

```
ng generate component my-component --no-spec
```

**Method 2:**
Permanently disable in angular.json file. You can edit the schematics for your project.

```
"schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "scss",
      "spec": false
    },
    "@schematics/angular:class": {
      "spec": false
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "spec": false
    },
    "@schematics/angular:guard": {
      "spec": false
    },
    "@schematics/angular:module": {
      "spec": false
    },
    "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
      "spec": false
    },
    "@schematics/angular:service": {
      "spec": false
    }
  },
```

Comment: is the `--no-spec` option documented anywhere? Couldn't find it in the [ng g c](https://angular.io/cli/generate#component) documentation, or `ng g c --help` in the command line.

Comment: use `--skipTests=true`  to generate without specs file

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this without altering the `angular.json` file is to use this command(tried this in v13 and v14):

```
ng generate component test-component --skip-tests true
```

If you want to generate the `ts` and `html` file only in a subfolder then you need to use this command:

```
ng generate component test-component --skip-tests true --style none
```

And if you need them without any subfolder then use the following command:

```
ng generate component test-component --skip-tests true --style none --flat
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// for ealier versions
ng generate component path/filename --no-spec
// Or
ng generate component path/filename --spec false

// for later versions
ng generate component path/filename --skipTests=true
// Note: path is relative to src/app folder
```