# Angular 6 - How to stop generating spec files

Tags: json, angular, testing, configuration

In Angular 5 and earlier versions, to stop generating the spec files while generationg a component we had to add the following in **.angular-cli.json** file:

```
{
  ...
  "defaults": {
    "spec": {
      "class": false,
      "component": false,
      "directive": false,
      "module": false,
      "pipe": false,
      "service": false
    }
  }
}
```

in Angular 6+, following [this link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/29c1d9d3afc5da93d0118876db39a93e5384b906/packages/%40angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json#L74-L144) we have to add the next in the new **angular.json** file, under the schematics section:

```
  ....
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      ....
      "properties": {
        ....
        "spec": {
          "type": "boolean",
          "description": "Specifies if a spec file is generated.",
          "default": false
        }
      }          
    }
  },
```

But when generating a new component a new spec file is still created, even after IDE restart, what is missing ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 6 + CLI (TypeScript) - How to stop generating .spec.ts test files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42049756/angular-6-cli-typescript-how-to-stop-generating-spec-ts-test-files)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to the link provided here by [G. Ross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50193766/generating-components-without-spec-ts-in-angular-6?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), the solution despite it doesn't match the official [documentation of Angular 6](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/29c1d9d3afc5da93d0118876db39a93e5384b906/packages/%40angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json#L74-L144) but it worked for me.

added the next in the "**angular.json**" file, under the schematics section:

```
  ....
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      ....
      "spec": false,
      ....
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 9):

You can set it in the angular-cli.json as

```
{
  "defaults": {
    "component": {
      "spec": false
    }
  }
}
```

This will disable generating all spec files. If you want to disable on a specific component,

```
ng g c component-name --spec false
```

Comment: You repeat what is in the question, please consider that I am asking how to set it in angular.json file not in .angular-cli.json, this question is related to Angular 6.

Comment: is not the same with angular.json as well?  "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "fmyp",
      "styleext": "css",
      "spec": false
    },

Comment: No sorry, not the same way, .angular-cli.json is deprecated for versions above 5.x.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use to generate a component without its spec files `ng g c NewComponent --spec=false`

Comment: This is not an automated way.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50193766/generating-components-without-spec-ts-in-angular-6?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: It worked despite this doesn't match the official documentation of Angular 6: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/29c1d9d3afc5da93d0118876db39a93e5384b906/packages/%40angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json#L74-L144

Comment: Please post a complete answer with explanation to help others, thank you.